# Roblox API ( Avatar Equipment )

Tags: php, api, roblox

I am currently working on Roblox API. I am stuck on one question.  Reason :
I have this link https://avatar.roblox.com/v1/users/2/currently-wearing.
This shows what specified users have equipped on them. this link right here shows this:
{"assetIds":[382537569,607702162,607785314]}
My goal is to get the assetIds to string.
I tried this:

```
<?php
$id = 2;
$ch = file_get_contents("https://avatar.roblox.com/v1/users/$id/currently-wearing");
$ch = curl_init($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

$data = json_decode($data);

$id = "$data->assetIds";
echo $id;
```

But it Shows Array. I need some help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cURL is not necessary as the `file_get_contents()` get you the data you appear to require

```
$id = 2;
$ch = file_get_contents("https://avatar.roblox.com/v1/users/2/currently-wearing");

$data = json_decode($ch);

foreach ($data->assetIds as $id){
    echo $id . PHP_EOL;
}
```

RESULT

```
382537569
607702162
607785314
```

Comment: Thank you so much I was trying to this for weeks.